# How to create a fancy box using jquery?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am new to jquery and now trying to create a fancy box in jquery . I will explain its functionality. When the user clicks on the image, it must be popped up in another window. Here, I have to use a smooth transition to show up the image. Now, I got the image in a new window but the transition was missing. Can I have your help?

Comment: it is already created using jQuery, use the same.

Comment: I guess you need to provide more information, it's difficult to guess what the problem is with what you said. Preferably share a link with a sample of the issue to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) plugin?

Comment: As you said i have included the jquery plugin in header section . here i put my code . if you find any mistake replaied to me .<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Fancy Box or Modal can be created in three ways:-

1. You can use Css, Jquery or javascript.
2. You can also use JqueryUI Library.[Click here to see JqueryUI modals Examples](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_dialog.htm)
3. The easiest way to create modal box is  use Bootstrap Framework. [Click here to see Bootstrap modals Examples](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)